# Download file with FileContentResult and store it client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, download

I've an MVC route as this:

```
public FileContentResult GetMedia(string media_md5)
{
    // get media from DB here 
    processed_file_doc file_doc = getMediaFromDb(media_md5);

    string filename = file_doc.Filename;
    string filepath = file_doc.File_path;

    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    string fileName = filename;

    FileContentResult file_result = File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);

    return file_result;
}
```

This method is called by javascript in this way:

```
function DownloadMedia(row_id) {

    filetable = $('#mytable').DataTable();
    var data = filetable.row('#' + row_id).data();
    filename = data['Filename'];

    var handleSuccess = function (file) {
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            file = new Blob([file], { type: "application/octect-stream" });
        
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a); 
            a.click();
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.body.removeChild(a);
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }, 0);     
    }

    $.post("/MyController/GetMedia", { media_md5: row_id }, handleSuccess);
}
```

The problem is that using this code I can correctly download only .txt files, if for example I try to download a .jpg, the image can't be opened. I've checked the two file downloaded and they are really different:

[image: file differences]

I've verified that the file is open and read correctly, but I can't understand why once received from client it is all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet
```

choose correct MimeType foreach file

Answer (score 0):

Try checking

1. The url for the file is correct with right extension
2. Errors logged in the browser console. (F12 to open developer tools > Console)

Answer (score 0):

Use octet-stream instead of octect-stream

Comment: Technically, yes, but does that result in the error given? Pointing out typos should be done in comments, not answers.

Comment: If this does indeed solve the problem, you need to explain why.